# React native: children view cannot go beyond parent view on Android but it is working on iOS

Tags: android, react-native

I have encountered a problem porting my app from iOS to android. I have built a minimal bug case with which it can be reproduced.

My app is very simple and consists of one component:

```
const Main = () => (
  <View>
    <View style= {styles.green}>
      <View style={styles.blue}/>
    </View>
  </View>
)

export default Main;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  green: {
    height:200,
    marginTop: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  blue:{
    position:'absolute',
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    top: -50,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
})
```

But strangely this component renders differently on iOS and Android

### iOS

[image: render ios]

### Android

[image: render android]

I would like it to render like on iOS on both devices. You can check code on this repo https://github.com/42void/ReactNativeBug to easily reproduce it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android `overflow` property defaults to `'hidden'` and cannot be changed.

[From 0.23 known issues](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/known-issues.html#the-overflow-style-property-defaults-to-hidden-and-cannot-be-changed-on-android), apparently isn't fixed yet.